# Change default title bar icon

Tags: gnome, x11, icons

How do I set the default title bar icon for X11 applications? The xterm on my machine is displaying an icon with a red x instead of the normal application-default icon. Changing themes in gnome doesn't help either.

Comment: Do you want to change the icon for xterm alone or for _all_ applications?

Comment: All applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this system-wide by changing the `Icon` value in the corresponding `.desktop` entry for `xterm`. These types of entries are usually located in `/usr/share/applications`. Look for the entry named something like `xterm.desktop` and set the `Icon` value to an image file located somewhere in `/usr/share/icons` i.e. `Icon=my_xterm_icon.png`. You might want to check if there is already some icons that you want to use there:

```
$ find /usr/share/icons -iname "*xterm*" -print
```

Apply this to all entries to have all X11 applications use the same icon.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the annoying XTerm icon, running the xterm command with an additional option: +ai   should remove that icon...